# highcharts transparent series

Tags: highcharts, transparent

I'm drawing a line chart with two series, one of them being transparent (but with colored points).

My problem is that the transparent series doesn't have a color in the legend, and it doesn't look good (especially when hiding it by clicking its name in the legend).

Here's an example of what I'm doing:
[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/topatidle/G4NLn/)

The code that creates the transparent series is:

```
{type:'spline',name:'Transparent',color:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)', data:[{x:1361059200000, y:0.0, marker: {symbol: "square", radius: 3, fillColor: "#f2a8a8", states: { hover: {radius: 3, fillColor: "#f2a8a8"}}}},{x:1361088000000, y:0.0, marker: {symbol: "square", radius: 8, fillColor: "#f2a8a8", states: { hover: {radius: 8, fillColor: "#f2a8a8"}}}},{x:1361116800000, y:0.0, marker: {symbol: "square", radius: 6, fillColor: "#f2a8a8", states: { hover: {radius: 6, fillColor: "#f2a8a8"}}}}]}
```

Is there a way to set a color to the series legend (either during chart creation or with JavaScript after the chart was created)?

Thanks,
Ziv

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using transparent spline I suggest to use scatter serie with customised markers.

http://jsfiddle.net/G4NLn/3/

```
 {
            type: 'scatter',
            name: 'Transparent',
            marker: {
                    symbol: "square",
                    radius: 3,
                    fillColor: "#f2a8a8",
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            radius: 3,
                            fillColor: "#f2a8a8"
                        }
                    }
             },
            //color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)',
            data: [{
                x: 1361059200000,
                y: 0.0,
                marker: {
                    symbol: "square",
                    radius: 3,
                    fillColor: "#f2a8a8",
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            radius: 3,
                            fillColor: "#f2a8a8"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, {
                x: 1361088000000,
                y: 0.0,
                marker: {
                    symbol: "square",
                    radius: 8,
                    fillColor: "#f2a8a8",
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            radius: 8,
                            fillColor: "#f2a8a8"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, {
                x: 1361116800000,
                y: 0.0,
                marker: {
                    symbol: "square",
                    radius: 6,
                    fillColor: "#f2a8a8",
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            radius: 6,
                            fillColor: "#f2a8a8"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it looks better. The last problem is that when hiding the scatter data set, the legend shows the symbol with a grey horizontal line, and I can't find a way to eliminate this line.

Comment: This line is not scatter element, but yAxis gridLines. Take look at gridLines options http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis

Comment: I'm familiar with it. What I don;t understand is how does it work OK in your fiddle. I don't see any settings regarding the color of the legend line.